# Advice on a catch all for https incoming but no cert installed

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, virtualhost, https

I am trying to think of an elegant way to handle an SSL / HTTPS issue we are having.  I have read [THIS QUESTION](https://serverfault.com/questions/843481/catch-all-https-vhost-on-apache-2-4) but it raises a slightly larger question in my case.

Say I have these domains installed on my server, each having it's own vhost configuration:

```
foo.com
bar.com
```

I have SSLs installed for both `foo` and for `bar`.  But the customer who owns `foo` also has a domain `widget.com` that they want forwarded to `foo.com`.  The only issue is `widget.com` has no SSL installed.  Now normally in a small environment the answer would be to install a certificate for `widget` -- It's only a few dollars and 10 mins of work ..  But when you have 4000+ domains, and at least twice that in "forwarded" domains ..  It gets unruly in a hurry.

I am wondering, would self signed certificates for all of these forwarded domains at least get me past the SSL Mismatch screen if someone manually puts the `https` in front of `widget.com` ?  If self signed doesn't work, what is an elegant solution to get `https://widget.com` to at least not get the `SSL Mismatch` error?  Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Using self signed certificates is a bad idea. Most people will not, and should not, click through the messages about a bad certificate. Browsers continually make it harder for people to do so.

You could buy certificates for each domain. Or a SAN certificate that has all the domains listed in it.

Or you could just use [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) and get free, trusted certificates that update themselves automatically. That's the way I would go. If you are actually talking about 4000 domains, you'd want to take a look at the API rate limiting for letsencrypt and make sure you aren't going to exceed that, but their limits are pretty generous I think.

Alternatively don't host all the redirected domains yourself. I think Cloudflare can do that for you, including SSL certificates, either really cheaply or possibly for free. There are probably similar services to do the same.

Comment: This is some great advice . Thank you.  I really didn't know if I was looking at it correctly ...  Which as you pointed out, I think I fell into the [XY Problem Trap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Zak Almost, but you included enough detail about the actual problem you're trying to solve, so you didn't fall into that particular trap!